# БРАНДМАУЭР как рекламный щит

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, терминология

БРАНДМАУЭР
    рекламный щит, маскирующий глухую стену.

Райзберг Б.А., Лозовский Л.Ш., Стародубцева Е.Б.. Современный экономический словарь. — 2-е изд., испр. М.: ИНФРА-М. 479 с.. 1999.

Как понять:  маскирующий глухую стену?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как понять: маскирующий глухую стену?**

Глухая стена — стена без проёмов (окон, дверей). Зрелище не особенно привлекательное. Вот эту непривлекательность и маскирует реклама (многим, наверное, вид рекламы нравится больше).

Answer (score 1):

1. О значении слова *маскировать*

> Являться, служить средством, которое делает что-, кого-л. незаметным, невидным. Рубашка маскирует худые плечи.
>   ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x))

Рекламный щит скрывает унылую глухую стену от наших глаз.

2. О значении слова БРАНДМАУЭР

> БРАНДМАУЭР, -а; м. [нем. Brandmauer] Глухая огнестойкая стена, разделяющая смежные строения или части строения в противопожарных целях. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%91%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%AD%D0%A0))
>
> БРАНДМАУЭР — (нем. Brandmauer, от Brand пожар, и Mauer стена). Каменная стена между двумя домами, воздвигаемая для того, чтобы локализировать действие пожара. Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка. Чудинов А.Н., 1910. (Словарь иностранных слов русского языка)
>
> Брандмауэр — противопожарная стена. Источник: Словарь архитектурно строительных терминов несгораемая, преимущественно глухая, капитальная стена, разделяющая здание на отсеки для предотвращения распространения пожара (Строительный словарь)

Каким образом БРАНДМАУЭР оказался рекламным щитом на этой стене, для меня загадка.

Comment: В Современной энциклопедии(2000г.) говорится, что "    БРАНДМАУЭР (немецкое Brandmauer), устаревшее название противопожарной стены".

Comment: Брандмауэр - в информатике - программный и/или аппаратный барьер между двумя сетями, позволяющий устанавливать только авторизованные межсетевые соединения. Брандмауэр защищает соединяемую с Интернет корпоративную сеть от проникновения извне и исключает возможность доступа к конфиденциальной информации.

Comment: Как видно из трактовок этого  слова, общего его значение - что-либо защищать. Вот и в нашем примере значение "рекламный щит" могло возникнуть по аналогии. Т.е. щит так сказать защищает, маскирует непривлекательность стены.

Comment: В Современной энциклопедии (2000 г.) что-то недопоняли: зданий с брандмауэрами полно, и другого слова в употреблении нет лучше. А щиты на глухих фасадах точно можно считать анахронизмом (только как вывески), рекламщики натягивают баннерную ткань, сетку или вешают экраны.

Comment: Совершенно с Вами согласна. Об этом я и написала ранее в своем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

[**Словарь по рекламе. 2010**](https://advertising.academic.ru/53/%D0%91%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%AD%D0%A0):
БРАНДМАУЭР
глухая стена здания, на которой крепится щитовая реклама, выкладывается панно или наносится изображение на штукатурку. Обычно реклама на брандмауэре больших размеров.

[**Словарь бизнес-терминов. 2001**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/business/1691):
**Брандмауэр**
рекламный щит, размещенный на глухой, без окон, стене здания.

Получается, что брандмауэр — это и противопожарная стена (файервол), и щит, и реклама, и глухая стена (без окон, без дверей и других проемов).

Я бы не стала относить значение брандмауэра как противопожарной стены к устаревшим. Например, [Глоссарий терминов по загородному домостроению](https://lesstroy.net/glossary/protivopozharnaya_stena/) его вовсю использует.